# UK pension auto enrollment - when would the assessment deem to remove an employee from a pension scheme?

Tags: united-kingdom, pension

I am currently working on a payroll IT project.  Part of this involves submitting payroll data to a third party API (PayRun.io) that will perform the assessment of the employee as to whether auto-enrolment into a pension is necessary.  i.e. if they are assessed as an "eligible job holder" as per the regulation.  I understand that eligible job holders must be auto-enrolled in pension schemes and can opt-out if they request.  So far so good..

However, the API can also return an assessment that the employee should be *removed* from a pension scheme.  I can't find anywhere in the regulation as to under what circumstances this would be? Under what conditions should someone be automatically removed from a pension scheme?  Other than if the employee themselves has chosen to opt out?

Comment: This is outside the scope of 'personal finance'.

Comment: Can't see anything in various guides to autoenrollment (for employers). Maybe ask the API provider?

Comment: That's not a valid outcome of an auto-enrolment assessment, you would have to speak to the API developers to understand why that's an option in the API